# SQL: Join with LIKE and min()

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, sql-like

I'm using the query below to fetch the lowest priced row(s) matching the LIKE.

```
Suppliers
id | name           
----------------------------------------
1  | sup1    
2  | sup2  

Prices
id | article_number | price | supplier_id  
------------------------------------------------
1  | 12345678       | 312  | 1
2  | 12345678       | 219  | 2
3  | 87654321       | 312  | 1


select prices.* from prices
inner join
( 
  select min(price) as price, 
  article_number as article_number from prices group by article_number
) 
min_prices on prices.price = min_prices.price 
and prices.article_number = min_prices.article_number 

WHERE prices.article_number LIKE '".$q."%'
```

Although now also want to fetch the suppliers.name from Suppliers-table:

```
select prices.*, suppliers.name from prices, suppliers 
inner join
( 
  select min(price) as price, 
  prices.article_number as article_number from prices group by prices.article_number
) 
min_prices on price = min_prices.price 
and article_number = min_prices.article_number 

WHERE 
        prices.article_number LIKE '".$q."%' AND
        prices.supplier_id = suppliers.id"
```

This returns 18-times the amount of rows it is supposed to...?

Also the table consists of 10+ millions rows, so efficiency is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance, add index on `article_number`, and use `prices.article_number LIKE '".$q."%'` in sub query. You'd better use `JOIN` not `,` (this is old way) to combine two tables. Like this:

```
select prices.*, suppliers.name
from prices
inner join ( 
  select min(price) as price, prices.article_number as article_number
  from prices
  where prices.article_number like '".$q."%'
  group by prices.article_number
) min_prices
on price = min_prices.price 
and article_number = min_prices.article_number
inner join suppliers
on prices.supplier_id = suppliers.id
where prices.article_number like '".$q."%'
```

Comment: shoot for output from `show create table tablexyz` for every relevant table.  Try to get some composite indexes in place, who knows, even a covered index. And of course, output from `explain` . A composite on `(price,article_number)` could be sweet depending on the width of `article_number`